# Implement Pixel tracking to track open rates in Google analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics

I am following the tutorial :

```
$var_utmac = 'UA-29940706-1'; //enter the new urchin code
$var_utmhn = 'mywebsite.com'; //enter your domain
$var_utmn = rand(1000000000,9999999999); //random request number
$var_cookie = rand(10000000,99999999); //random cookie number
$var_random = rand(1000000000,2147483647); //number under 2147483647
$var_today = time(); //today
$utm_source = 'newsletter';
$utm_medium = 'email';
$utm_campaign = 'newsletter111';
$var_uservar = '-'; //enter your own user defined variable
$var_utmp = 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15672207/web.png'; //this example adds a fake file request to the (fake) tracker directory (the image/pdf filename).
$urchinUrl = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=1&utmn='.$var_utmn.'&utmsr=-&utmsc=-&utmul=-&utmje=0&utmfl=-&utmdt=-&utmhn='.$var_utmhn.'&utm_source='.$utm_source.'&utm_medium='.$utm_medium.'&utm_campaign='.$utm_campaign.'&utmp='.$var_utmp.'&utmac='.$var_utmac.'&utmcc=__utma%3D'.$var_cookie.'.'.$var_random.'.'.$var_today.'.'.$var_today.'.'.$var_today.'.2%3B%2B__utmb%3D'.$var_cookie.'%3B%2B__utmc%3D'.$var_cookie.'%3B%2B__utmz%3D'.$var_cookie.'.'.$var_today.'.2.2.utmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B%2B__utmv%3D'.$var_cookie.'.'.$var_uservar.'%3B';

// Now fire off the HTTP request
$handle = fopen ($urchinUrl, "r");
$test = fgets($handle);
fclose($handle);

// Redirect this script as an actual GIF file sitting on this web server
header('Location: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15672207/web.png');
```

I can now track the open rate of this script in Google Analytics. But does that mean I can have **one Google Analytics account for one campaign** only? And does it take a day before it actually collect data?

Comment: interesting, i saw someone has use the code. Please kindly help me to solve some problem

Comment: i can  simply <img src='google.php'>, ok , 1 problem sloved

Answer (score 2):

Please don't duplicate your own questions : [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004644/how-to-know-the-number-of-recipient-have-open-the-email-through-google-analytic), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005593/using-utm-gif-for-google-analytic-to-track-the-open-rate/10005862#10005862), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971444/how-to-use-google-analytics-to-track-open-rates-click-rates-in-a-email)

We can not give you a response if your reasoning is dipersed between several threads...

Comment: sorry since the type of question is different but it is on the same topic.though, Sorry